# Automatic form submission and calculation

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm new to web design, so hopefully this is an easy question. I have something such as this...

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">

Height: <input type="text" name="height" value=""><br>
Width: <input type="text" name="width" value=""><br>

</form>

<p>The area of the of the box is [output = height * width]</p>
```

I would like the Height and Width input boxes to be pre-populated with data from the database if the user has previously submitted the data. If not, I'd like the input box to contain "0.00". Additionally, I'd like the output box to automatically calculate when the input boxes are populated and I'd like any new input for Height and/or Width to be submitted to the database in place of any current data without the user having to press a submit button. So perhaps on a tab out event.

Can you help me? I am using php and mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a jFiddle which is working for the height.

http://jsfiddle.net/R6NJ2/

you need to use the javascript library jQuery to achieve this.

```
 jQuery('.height').change(updateHeight);
    jQuery('.height').keyup(updateHeight);
```

is firing update Events when the input is changed by user input.

```
function updateHeight() {

    var remaining = jQuery('.height').val()
    jQuery('.output').text(remaining );


    updateCountdown();
};
```

this reads the value first and then write it then into your target element.
After this you can calculate with the variable 'remaining' and the one your going to
create for the width with the same logic

```
var result = remaining * yourWidthVariable
jQuery('.resultContainer).text(result);
```

this should be a good start to go further on your task (sending to php, submit values etc)

PS: You can get a Int to Double with  `Number.toFixed` iE `(100).toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 0):

To populate your field, use the value attribute.
To send data when changing values or just to calculate the ouput use the onblur event

```
<?php $width = your logic here (or 0.00)
$height =your logic here (or 0.00)
?>
<form action="process.php" method="POST" id="myform">

Height: <input type="text" name="height" onblur="document.getElementById('myform').submit();" value="<?php echo $height?>"><br>
Width: <input type="text" name="width" onblur="document.getElementById('myform').submit();"  value="<?php echo $width ?>"><br>

</form>
```